# Switching between an AC unit and a water heater off a single power source

Tags: electrical

I have an AC unit and water heater installed but there is only one power source. I have an MCB installed so to change between the ac unit and water heater I turn off the MCB(Miniature Circuit Breaker) and change the wires. I wanted to know is there is any switch or other hardware which I can use to switch between the appliances when I turn on the MCB. Like the switch is connected to the MCB and the appliances are connected to the switch so whenever I turn on the MCB the appliance which the switch is selected to gets turned on. I live in India so I get 220V to my home. Thanks if any more info is required please inform me.

Comment: Similar: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/136377/i-need-to-switch-between-two-240v-30a-loads

Comment: we are a international web site, MCB can mean anything, spell it out. Like Main Circuit Breaker

Comment: Otoh no one explains Anerican terms such ad gfc... whatever. In many diverse parts of the world MCB means miniature circuit breaker. They plug into the old style ceramic fuse wire holders.

Answer (score 5):

There are  a few ways to do it and they may not be legal in USA. But they work down under

1. Mount two circuit breakers, one to each load. And flick one off and one on.
2. Leave the breaker as is and use a 32A or 63A changeover switch such to switch between the two loads.

For [demonstration](https://www.tlc-direct.co.uk/Products/KMT338212I.html)

[image]

Comment: Well, "down under" (AU/NZ) is similar to India wiring-wise.  Though y'all use our junction box shapes for some reason lol.